# CouchDB SSL decode error

Tags: ssl, openssl, couchdb

I can't get CouchDB working over SSL. The certificates are fine, and indeed I have tested with self signed, and the test certificates for Couch at https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/examples/https/

It's an Ubuntu box, running couch 1.6.1 and the SSL certificates all check out when checked at https://www.digicert.com/help/

The error does not appear when testing via curl, but does when attempting connection from a browser. The error line in the log is:

```
SSL: certify: tls_connection.erl:375:Fatal error: decode error
```